# /bin/sh: eval: line 98: bash: not found

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

i got this

```
/bin/sh: eval: line 98: bash: not found
```

message by executing the gitlabb .yml file.

I added in the before script section the line

```
- apk update && apk add openssh
```

which was not helpful.

```
before_script:
  - apk update && apk add openssh
  - bash docker_install.sh > /dev/null

stages:
  - build
  - deploy
  - loadtest-local

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "building my application in ubuntu container..."

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: php:7.4
  script: 
    - phpunit Unittest.php
    

loadtest-local:
  image: 
    name: loadimpact/k6:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  stage: loadtest-local
  script:
    - k6 run ./loadtests/performance-test.js
    - k6 run ./loadtests/inttest.js
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 6):

That means one of the images used in your pipeline doesn't have bash installed.

Try changing the line on `before_script` to `./docker_install.sh > /dev/null` (make sure the `docker_install.sh` has execution permissions set beforehand).

Comment: chmod +x ./docker_install.sh > /dev/null is this the right approach for the permission?
Now I have a problem in the deploy stage: /bin/bash: line 102: phpunit: command not found.

Comment: It doesn't seem like the `php:7.4` image has `phpunit` installed, you either need to install it or check out https://hub.docker.com/r/phpunit/phpunit/

Comment: If I got the bash: not found error. The deploy stage was successful.

Answer (score 3):

This fixed the issue for me.

```
before_script:
    - apk add --no-cache --upgrade bash
```